# SendKeys.send with internet explorer

Tags: c#

The command below does not output correctly in internet explorer 8.

```
SendKeys.Send("Testing");
```

I also tried copyying the text to clipboard and emulating ctrl-v but that did not work also.

What is the correct way to automate data input into IE 8

Comment: If you want to automate applications the "correct" way, then you ought to be looking at the [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open an Internet Explorer window, the only place you can enter text is an input control, such as a textbox or combo box,etc. What your SendKeys statement is basically trying to do is overwrite the existing content displayed on the web page.

if you want to test the functionality of sendkeys, try it with the Notepad text editor, using this example:

```
    Dim w As New SendKeys.WINFOCUS
    w = SendKeys.GetWinHandles("New Text Document - Notepad", 1, "Edit", 1)
    SendKeys.Send("Hello", w)
```

That code snippet came from codeguru: [SendKeys discussion and examples](http://www.codeguru.com/vb/gen/vb_system/keyboard/article.php/c14629/SendKeys.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Taking an example of data input in the textbox of www.google.com

```
SHDocVw.InternetExplorer IE=new InternetExplorer();
object URL = "www.google.com";
IE.Visible = true;
IE.Navigate2(ref URL);
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000); // You can put some custom conditions here such as ready state/document complete/page complete events as an indicator when the page has completely loaded 
mshtml.HTMLDocument doc=(mshtml.HTMLDocument)IE.Document;
IHTMLInputElement textBox = (IHTMLInputElement)doc.getElementById("lst-ib"); //lst-ib is the unique id of the textbox in which you want to set a value
textBox.value = "Testing";
```